# Groovy servlet on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, groovy, gaelyk

I've just created a google app engine project and I would like to use groovy servlets. I have placed groovy-all in the lib folder  and the mapping in the web.xml. When I try to access the servlet I've an exception:
access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect")

I know that there is Gealyk but I would like to know what exactly happen and why... I suppose is something related to the class loading or compiling? How Gaelyk handle this problem??

Comment: It should work. Maybe there is something with your configuration. See the Template Project: http://gaelyk.appspot.com/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [open issue in Groovy](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6405). You can use [my own snapshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pjz40xyld314gdi/rqbIhNJvyP/groovy-for-appengine) before the issue is fixed and released.